# Showing $PSL(2,9)$ doesn't have a subgroup of order $90$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, linear-groups

I got stuck in proving that there is not any subgroup of order $90$ in group $PSL(2,9) = SL(2,9)/Z(SL(2,9))$. Can anyone help?

Comment: It would be nice if you give a broad overview of things you've tried. I like the question, and I'd prefer if it stayed open.

Comment: thank you very much @pjs36 I'm trying to get some ideas to prove it but....

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that ${\rm PSL}(2,9)$ is simple?

Comment: yes @DerekHolt.

Comment: Then such a subgroup would have index $4$ and the action by multiplication on its cosets would define a nontrivial homomorphism ${\rm PSL}(2,9) \to S_4$, which is impossible.

Comment: thanks a lot @DerekHolt. It's clear to me now.